# SQL Select distinct records from a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table like this:

[image]

And the desired result would be:

[image]

And here's the explantion:

The result should only pick the max ActivityCount column with distinct column UserName, RemarkID, CreatedBy and CreatedDate

I've tried using groupby but there's an error

```
Column 'ActivityCount' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
```

And here's the SQL script using group by

```
select * from TableName group by UserName, RemarkID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate
```

What changes are needed to the script in order to get the desired result?

Comment: Do you need the ID column also?

Comment: No Actually I don't need the ID column..

Comment: Then select the columns in the group by plus MAX(ActivityCount) instead of * and you should be fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest approach would be using `ROW_NUMBER` and a CTE:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT t.*,
       RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY UserName, RemarkID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate
                               ORDER BY ActivityCount DESC)
    FROM dbo.TableName t 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE WHERE RN = 1
```

If you want to see all records with the highest `ActivityCount` per group (in case there are multiple) you can use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `ROW_NUMBER`.

[Ranking Functions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189798.aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT UserName, RemarkID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, MAX(ActivityCount)
FROM TableName
GROUP BY UserName, RemarkID, CreatedBy, CreatedDate
```

Comment: You can add `Max(id) as Id` to the select list.